# TypeError: b is null in joomla 3.1 component

Tags: custom-component, joomla3.0

I joomla component when the New/save/delete toolbar is clicked, It displays " TypeError: b is null". I'm try to build the component in joomla 3.1..

I referred

http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_configuration
 http://www.tutsforu.com/adding-toolbar-at-backend-of-joomla-component.html.

Please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to put the id = attribute in the form adminForm
form name = "adminForm" id = "adminForm"

Comment: It works for me too. Do you know why is this happening?